# On click of XCode Preferences, XCode hangs

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I am trying to access my XCode preferences but when I click on it, XCode hangs infinitely. On ForceQuit, I get a window to report error as below : I updated my XCode from 4.6.2 to 4.6.3 as well but no luck.

```
Date/Time:       2013-09-17 14:17:32 +0530
OS Version:      10.7.5 (Build 11G63)
Architecture:    x86_64
Report Version:  9

Command:         Xcode
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Version:         4.6.3 (2068)
Build Version:   3
Project Name:    IDEApplication
Source Version:  2068000000000000
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 15588541
Parent:          launchd [244]

PID:             40131
Event:           hang
Duration:        0.83s
Steps:           9 (100ms sampling interval)

Pageins:         0
Pageouts:        0


Process:         Xcode [40131]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Architecture:    x86_64
UID:             501

  Thread 0x1974e      DispatchQueue 1
  User stack:
    9 ??? (in Xcode) [0x109b89b00]
      9 ??? (in Xcode) [0x109b89b6f]
        9 NSApplicationMain + 867 (in AppKit) [0x7fff87a00eac]
          9 -[NSApplication run] + 470 (in AppKit) [0x7fff877849b9]
            9 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135 (in AppKit) [0x7fff8778807d]
              9 _DPSNextEvent + 2019 (in AppKit) [0x7fff87788cc9]
                9 _NSHandleCarbonMenuEvent + 250 (in AppKit) [0x7fff877f31da]
                  9 _HandleMenuSelection2 + 580 (in HIToolbox) [0x7fff8d5af592]
                    9 _ZL14MenuSelectCoreP8MenuData5PointdjPP13OpaqueMenuRefPt + 600 (in HIToolbox) [0x7fff8d5affc9]
                      9 _ZL19FinishMenuSelectionP13SelectionDataP10MenuResultS2_ + 101 (in HIToolbox) [0x7fff8d5b8883]
                        9 SendMenuItemSelectedEvent + 253 (in HIToolbox) [0x7fff8d6ee5b5]
                          9 SendMenuCommandWithContextAndModifiers + 56 (in HIToolbox) [0x7fff8d6a6e2d]
                            9 _ZL18SendHICommandEventjPK9HICommandjjhPKvP20OpaqueEventTargetRefS5_PP14OpaqueEventRef + 398 (in HIToolbox) [0x7fff8d5bf7b5]
                              9 SendEventToEventTarget + 76 (in HIToolbox) [0x7fff8d5796db]
                                9
```

Comment: Does this happen *every* time you try to go into your Xcode preferences? You may need to [completely reset your Xcode preferences to their defaults](http://www.ehow.com/how_11414414_reset-xcode.html).

Comment: Yes It happens every time. I followed the steps mentioned in the link you specified but its still the same.